# How to achieve high TLB miss?

Tags: c, memory, tlb

I'm trying to write a piece of code that achieves a very high TLB miss rate (over 95%). I have come up with the following `C` code that could reach around 30% d-TLB misses.

I use 4096 bytes page size on an Intel x86_64 processor and Ubuntu 20.04 (kernel v5.4).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MEMORY_SIZE (1024 * 1024 * 1024)
#define PAGE_SIZE 4096
#define PAGE_COUNT (MEMORY_SIZE / PAGE_SIZE)

typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef byte Page[PAGE_SIZE];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    register int loop = 3000;
    Page *pages = (Page *)malloc(PAGE_COUNT * sizeof(Page));
    while (loop-- > 0)
    {
        for (register int i = 0; i < PAGE_COUNT; ++i)
        {
            register int page_num = (i % 2) ? i : PAGE_COUNT - i;
            pages[page_num][0]++;
        }
    }
    free(pages);
    return 0;
}
```

To compile: `$ gcc main.c -o main`

To Run and measure using *perf* command: `$ sudo perf stat -e dTLB-loads-misses,dTLB-loads ./main`

And here is the output:

```sh
Performance counter stats for './main':

       521,160,735      dTLB-loads-misses         #   28.02% of all dTLB cache accesses
     1,860,126,043      dTLB-loads                                                  

      12.759230463 seconds time elapsed

      12.429918000 seconds user
       0.328050000 seconds sys
```

The output of the `cpuid` command containing my TLB information:

```sh
   cache and TLB information (2):
      0x63: data TLB: 2M/4M pages, 4-way, 32 entries
            data TLB: 1G pages, 4-way, 4 entries
      0x03: data TLB: 4K pages, 4-way, 64 entries
      0x76: instruction TLB: 2M/4M pages, fully, 8 entries
      0xb5: instruction TLB: 4K, 8-way, 64 entries
      0xc3: L2 TLB: 4K/2M pages, 6-way, 1536 entries
```

The question is, how to achieve much higher TLB misses (over 95%)?

Thanks

Comment: I have recently seen a question which also asked about how to achieve TLB misses without explaining what that is supposed to be. Surprisingly similar. Was that also one of yours? If so, what is the new aspect in this question?

Comment: The access pattern is still very regular, have you tried something more random?

Comment: @tstanisl Yes. I tried accessing the same memory by generating random numbers between 0 and PAGE_COUNT. But that way misses will be as low as ~3-5%.

Comment: `register` - that stopped doing anything back in the 1990's.

Comment: @Yunnosch: Correct, was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70600028/how-to-achieve-100-tlb-miss (now deleted)

Comment: @MohammadSiavashi using a syscall such as rand() will take more than a bit of your cpu time, hence lower TLB misses. Ideally you want to execute as few instructions as possible, while still keeping the memory access somewhat random.